# Run multiple python programs through a batch file on docker CE desktop(windows)

Tags: python, docker, batch-file

I have 3 python script which I want to run at the same time through batch file on docker CE windows.

I have created 3 containers for 3 python scripts. All the 3 python require input files.

python_script_1 : docker-container-name
python_script_2 : docker-container-name
python_script_2 : docker-container-name

The docker files for 3 python scripts are:

```
Docker_1

FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install pandas
COPY input.csv ./
COPY script.py ./
CMD ["python", "./script.py", "input.csv"]


Docker_2

FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install pandas
COPY input_itgear.txt ./
COPY script.py ./
CMD ["python", "./script.py", "input_itgear.txt"]


Docker_3

FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install pandas
COPY sale_new.txt ./
COPY store.txt ./
COPY script.py ./
CMD ["python", "./script.py", "sale_new.txt", "store.txt"]
```

I want to run all the three scripts at the same time on docker through a batch file. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with batch programming yourself? I am not, but my approach would simply be using docker-compose to define all 3 services to use each of the Dockerfiles and then from the .bat file just execute the `docker-compose up -d` command

Comment: If you need an example of the actual docker-compose file let me know

Comment: I am new to docker also to batch programming. It would be great if you can show the example of `docker-compose` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so here is the gist

https://gist.github.com/karlisabe/9f0d43fe09536efa8035092ccbb593d4

You need to place your csv and py files accordingly so that they can be copied into the images, but what is going to happen is that when you run `docker-compose up -d` it should build the images (or use from cache if no changes are made) and run all 3 services. In essence it's like using `docker run my-image` 3 times but there is some additional features available, like all 3 of the containers will be a special network created by docker. You should read more about docker-compose here https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: Thanks, I was just going through the docker-compose document. Sorry for the lame question, but where am I suppose to save the `.yml` file. I have already pushed the containers to repository.

Comment: The .yml file must be present when you are running the docker-compose up command. So depending on how and where you run it I would say it should be available for the .bat file. If you wish to simply have the .bat file without any additional files with it (which makes sense) they you should simply define that in the .bat file you wish to run 3 separate containers with `docker run -d --rm name-of-image`. The -d means that the container will be run in --detached mode (similar to screen command) and the --rm means that the container will be removed when the command is executed.

Comment: But the system you want to run this .bat file on obviously needs to have docker or docker-compose available (depending on which route you are taking)

Comment: Im working on windows 10 system and it has docker CE desktop. I don't have the  `.bat` file yet. Im not familiar in how to create that. is there any way this can we done with `.bat` file.

Comment: I haven't written any bat files myself, but can give it a shot. Gimme a miniute

Comment: Ok... So literally just typing
`docker run -it --rm alpine echo "Test"` in a regular txt file and then changing the extension to .bat allowed me to run the batch file and execute the docker command...
https://gist.github.com/karlisabe/51ea3b6a4087397b2c39dc71391084aa
This is literally all you need (just replace the image-name1/2/3 with your image names)

Comment: Im getting image not found locally, unable to log in

Comment: Then you need to first log in with docker

Comment: I have made the docker_batch_file like you mentioned.

Comment: Are you pushing the images to a public repository? Are they built on the same machine you are running them on?

Comment: Yup, same machine and public repository also log in was successful from powershell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195191/discussion-between-k-s-and-krlis-bele).